# Show company name in contacts

Tags: iphone, contacts

I'm at work and I'd like to call one of our suppliers, Acme Corp.  I've already saved the contact for our current Acme rep on my iPhone.  Today our rep is Pete, but recently it was Susie, and in the future it might be Phil.  I don't remember what the rep's name is off the top of my head, but I do care that they're the person to call for Acme.

How can I see the company name in my contacts list while still recording the rep's name?

Answer (score 2):

Just enter the company name and omit the first and last name of the representative. Put the numbers under category Work or Main. You can have more than one entry in any particular category, unlike Android.

Comment: This is pretty good, but I'd also like to keep the rep's name somewhere since it's going to come up in my dealings with that company.  (I've edited the question to clarify this.)

Comment: @Joe You could always type them into the “notes” field at the bottom of every contact.

Comment: Or you could replace the description of the individual phone numbers with “Phil”, “Pete”, and “Susie”... instead of work and main...

Answer (score 0):

Make your contacts with as much info as you have.

Using your example, make one for Pete as first name, no last name, and put acme in as the company.

Repeat again for Susie and Phil. Adding acme as the company to each.

Now open contacts and type acme in the search box.  You find all 3.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app specifically made for this called "Contacts by Company".
I believe it works on Mac and iPhone.